# How to split a string into a specific number of words and put it together as a single sentence in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to split a big string into 5 words and return a sentence from these 5 words. Example:

```
// The string that needs to be split
'Hello, this is a very big string that goes on for loooooooooong'

// The output i need
'Hello, this is a very
```

I know I can use `split(' ', 5)` to separate the first 5 words, but i don't know how to put them back together into a sentence. Thanks in advance for your help and i you need me to clearer just ask.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to rejoin the splitted array:

```
split(' ', 5).join(' ');
```

Comment: I found that out literally 20 seconds after i asked the question. Thank you very much anyway, i'll verify you answer in 12 min.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Array.prototype.join()` which  creates and returns a new string by concatenating all of the elements in an array.

```js
const s = 'Hello, this is a very big string that goes on for loooooooooong';

const str = s.split(' ', 5).join(' ');

console.log(str);
```

More about `Array.prototype.join()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve the result using [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and using regex `/\s+/`

[image]

```js
const str = "Hello, this is a very big string that goes on for loooooooooong";

const result = str.split(/\s+/).slice(0, 5).join(" ");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What does the `/\s+/` on split means?